# Renaming files with no fixed char length in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am currently learning **Python 2.7** and am really impressed by how much it can do.

Right now, I'm working my way through basics such as functions and loops. I'd reckon a more 'real-world' problem would spur me on even further.

I use a satellite recording device to capture TV shows etc to hard drive.

The naming convention is set by the device itself. It makes finding the shows you want to watch after the recording more difficult to find as the show name is preceded with lots of redundant info...

The recordings (in `.mts` format) are dumped into a folder called "HBPVR" at the root of the drive. I'd be running the script on my Mac when the drive is connected to it.

```
Example.
"Channel_4_+1-15062015-2100-Exams__Cheating_the_....mts"
or
"BBC_Two_HD-19052015-2320-Newsnight.mts"
```

I included the double-quotes.

I'd like a Python script that (ideally) would remove the broadcaster name, reformat the date info, strip the time info and then put the show's name to the front of the file name.

`E.g "BBC_Two_HD-19052015-2320-Newsnight.mts"` ->> "Newsnight 19 May 2015.mts"

What may complicate matters is that the broadcaster names are not all of equal length.

The main pattern is that broadcaster name runs up until the first hyphen.

I'd like to be able to re-run this script at later points for newer recordings and not have already renamed recordings renamed further.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried splitting by hyphens?

Comment: I haven't used pythons regular expression module for some time, but this may be a nice application for it.  As you noted, the strings are of varying length.  This is a suggestion in addition to splitting the string on hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import calendar

input = "BBC_Two_HD-19052015-2320-Newsnight.mts"

# Remove broadcaster name
input = '-'.join(input.split("-")[1:])

# Get show name
show = ''.join(' '.join(input.split("-")[2:]).split(".mts")[:-1])

# Get time string
timestr = ''.join(input.split("-")[0])

day = int(''.join(timestr[0:2])) # The day is the first two digits
month = calendar.month_name[int(timestr[2:4])] # The month is the second two digits
year = timestr[4:8] # The year is the third through sixth digits

# And the new string:
new = show + " " + str(day) + " " + month + " " + year + ".mts"

print(new) # "Newsnight 19 May 2015.mts"
```

I wasn't quite sure what the '2320' was, so I chose to ignore it.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Coder256.

That has given me a bit more insight into how Python can actually help solve real world (first world!) problems like mine.

It tried it out with some different combos of broadcaster and show names and it worked.

I would like though to use the script to rename a batch of recordings/files inside the folder from time to time.

The script did throw and error when processing an already re-named recording, which is to be expected I guess. Should the renamed file have a special character at the start of its name to help avoid this happening?

```
e.g "_Newsnight 19 May 2015.mts"
```

Or is there a more aesthetically pleasing way of doing this, with special chars being added on etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this, since you have a defined pattern is to use regular expressions:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import re
>>> s = "BBC_Two_HD-19052015-2320-Newsnight.mts"
>>> ts, name = re.findall(r'.*?-(\d{8}-\d{4})-(.*?)\.mts', s)[0]
>>> '{} {}.mts'.format(name, datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, '%d%m%Y-%H%M').strftime('%d %b %Y'))
'Newsnight 19 May 2015.mts'
```